# How to put text inside Rectangle in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, text, annotations

I am using [Rectangle](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html?searchHighlight=rectangle&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) to create a fishnet in MATLAB. Each box of the fishnet shows some value that I am reading from a matrix.

[image]

In the attached figure white boxes represent `NaN`, whereas yellow boxes have numbers like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.. Here, I want to write these numbers inside the yellow boxes.

How to do this? Below is my script,

```
for row=1:size(Data,1)
    for col=1:size(Data,2);

        if isnan(Data(row,col))
            rectangle('Position',[col-0.5 row 1 1], 'FaceColor','w','EdgeColor','k', 'LineWidth', 0.1)
        else
            rectangle('Position',[col-0.5 row 1 1], 'FaceColor','y','EdgeColor','k', 'LineWidth', 0.1)
            axis equal            
            str = num2str(Data(row,col));
            annotation('String',str);         
        end

        set(gca,'Visible','off')  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this under your str line:

```
text('Position',[row col],'string',str)
```